# Can't ssh to my PC using localtunnel

Tags: ssh

I can't access my router so I'm trying to use `localtunnel` to be able to ssh into the PC.

The problem is that when I run `lt -`

```
milano@milano-desktop:~$ lt --port 8080
your url is: https://blue-seahorse-65.loca.lt
```

But when I try to `ssh` from another computer, it asks for password. The problem is that my password doesn't work.

```
milano@milano-lenovo:~/PycharmProjects$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa milano@blue-seahorse-65.loca.lt
The authenticity of host 'blue-seahorse-65.loca.lt (193.34.76.44)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:uaIsG7KMxmF+VfmL81UgIQGwGmpPylVskMeSjjZD+nI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'blue-seahorse-65.loca.lt' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
milano@blue-seahorse-65.loca.lt's password:
```

The first problem is that it shouldn't ask for the password since I use `key` and the second one is that the password doesn't work.

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> `Localtunnel` will assign you a unique publicly accessible url that will proxy all requests to your **locally running webserver**.

(emphasis mine)

> Do you know where is the problem?

You are not connecting to your own host but to the ssh server at `loca.lt`. You need to have a (running) local webserver, and it will *exposed* at the above URL.

That is not meant for `ssh`. Though you could eventually build a tunnel on top of that, to use `ssh`.